# how to set Set-VMFirmware on a single line in powershell

Tags: c#, powershell

i am trying to make a small c# application to create my Hyper V VM's but i has got a problem with powershell in c# so i just running every powershell cmdlet using cmd.exe

but now i cant get how to set dvddrive as firstbootdevice in generation 2 virtual machine in just one line
for powershell script i use

```
$VMNAME= "SQL3"
$VMDVD = Get-VMDvdDrive -VMName $VMNAME
Set-VMFirmware -VMName $VMNAME -FirstBootDevice $VMDVD
```

but how can i do it in a single line

Comment: Why do you need a single line?

Comment: Replace the newlines with semi-colons

Comment: i am using cmd.exe to run powershell script i cant set variables in that so i need it to be single line

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a general rule, any variable reference can be substituted by a subexpression (`$()`):

```
Set-VMFirmware -VMName "SQL3" -FirstBootDevice $(Get-VMDvdDrive -VMName "SQL3")
```

Comment: you saved my day and i just added -ControllerLocation like     Set-VMFirmware -VMName "SQL3" -FirstBootDevice $(Get-VMDvdDrive -VMName "SQL3" -ControllerLocation  $contollernumber) so  i can add a specific dvddrive if i have more than one Thank You So much for help

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple DVD drives and know the ISO file

```
$DvdBootDrive = Get-VMDvdDrive -VMName $VmName | where {$_.Path -Like "*AutoInstall.iso*" }
Set-VMFirmware -VMName $VmName -FirstBootDevice $DvdBootDrive
```

Comment: this wont be single line at all i accepted the above answer as it is works for me